# Error: Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. (BehaviorSubject)

Tags: angular, rxjs, behaviorsubject, method-signature

I can supply a dummy application that demonstrates this, but it boils down to the following:
Service file: dialog.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class DialogService  {
  public TriggerDlgAction: BehaviorSubject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.TriggerDlgAction = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false); // initialize
  }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import { DialogService } from './dialog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit { 
  triggerValue: boolean = false;

  constructor(private dlgSvc: DialogService ) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.dlgSvc.TriggerDlgAction.subscribe(
      (doTrigger) => {
        this.triggerValue = doTrigger;
        console.log(this.triggerValue);
      }
    )
  } 
}
```

And the client.component.ts (whose module is imported into app.module.ts.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.css']
})
export class ClientComponent {

  constructor(protected dlgSvc: DialogService) { }

  RequestAppFunction() {
    this.dlgSvc.TriggerDlgAction<boolean>(true);
  }
}
```

And the error I don't understand:
[image]

Thanks in advance, :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the issue is coming from you trying to call with just `true`, as the behaviour subject would not expect to be called like this.

Behaviour Subjects are required to be called with `next()` and the value passed in here, in order to get them to emit to their subscribers.

Try amending the following code.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DialogService } from '../dialog.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-client',
  templateUrl: './client.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./client.component.css']
})
export class ClientComponent {

  constructor(protected dlgSvc: DialogService) { }

  RequestAppFunction() {
    this.dlgSvc.TriggerDlgAction.next(true);
                               ^^^^^^^^^
  }
}
```

Comment: ARGH!  I knew better than that!  You are absolutely correct.  Thanks for pointing that out.  Sorry for wasting your time.  :-)  Chuck aka Yogi

Comment: Glad to help :-)